# Роутинг в Вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, роутинг

Приветствую.
Есть шаблон, который выводит некоторый список записей, а в админке есть страница, к которой привязан этот шаблон. При нажатии на один из элементов списка должна открываться страница с подробной информацией о нем. Однако я не могу разобраться как реализовать такую возможность на вордпрессе.

Т.е., список отображается на странице с урлом: site.ru/catalog/ - страница всегда отображает список записей
А вот элементы списка должны находится по адресу: site.ru/catalog/product_1, site.ru/catalog/product_2 и тд.

Может подскажет кто как это сделать ? Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите фрагмент шаблона, который отвечает за вывод списка. Как получаете список? Как настроены постоянные ссылки в админке Вордпресса (Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки)? Иначе непонятно, в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: @Ponio Вот так я вывожу список на условной странице site.ru/catalog/ :
    $posts = array_reverse(get_posts(array("numberposts" => "999")));

            foreach ($posts as $post){
                setup_postdata($post);
                $cat = get_the_category();

Таким образом я вывожу список всех нужных записей, теперь если на странице кликнуть на элемент "Элемент 1" из этого списка, то необходимо, чтобы меня перенаправило на site.ru/catalog/element_1.

У меня есть шаблон для вывода этого элемента, только вот как фраймворку дать понять, что нужно отобразить этот шаблон ?

Comment: Урлы стоят Произвольно: /%category%/%postname%/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, на странице `site.ru/catalog` выводится список заголовков постов, при клике на заголовок поста происходит переход на страницу поста.

```
$posts = array_reverse(get_posts(
    array("numberposts" => "999"))); // если вам нужны все посты, то лучше в этом параметре писать "-1"

foreach ($posts as $post){ 
    setup_postdata($post); 
    $cat = get_the_category(); // оставила ваш код
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); // выводим ссылку на страницу поста 
    ?>">
        <?php the_title(); // выводит заголовок поста 
    ?>
    </a>
    <?php 
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // желательно сбрасывать данные глобальной переменной $post, которые были установлены с помощью функции setup_postdata
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Вывод списка у меня как раз так и реализован, просто я код не до конца вставил, ибо лимит символов на комментарий   не позволял. Тут все понятно, список выводится как надо. Вопрос в том, что когда я нажимаю на ссылку, меня адресует на site.ru/catalog/element_1, а такой страницы у меня нет. Если, скажем, страница каталога неизменна, т.е. я создал ее в админке и привязал шаблон с данным пхп-кодом, то страницы на элементы этого каталога у меня, я просто напросто не знаю как ее создать так, чтобы не пришлось создавать по странице на каждый каталог.

Comment: В иных цмс, за роутинг обычно отвечает какой-либо файл, вроде urlrewrite.php или urls.py или еще какие, где можно указать при помощи регулярок, с какими урлами какой шаблон отображать. Т.е. там это вроде того сделано:
/catalog/$" => "catalog.html",
/catalog/<element_slug> => "element.html"

А вот с вп я лишь пару дней разбираюсь, и пока что понял, что раз данная цмс предназначена для блогов, то и роутинга тут не надо. Потому и интересуюсь про его реализацию.

Comment: Что такое каталог в вашем понимании? Вы писали, что шаблон ссылки у вас `/%category%/%postname%/`, значит, URL каждого поста содержит сначала название категории, а затем название поста. Так и есть?

Comment: Да, так и есть. Не знаю как объяснить, чтобы Вы меня поняли :). Если зайти на site.ru/catalog, то у меня открываться страница category.php, потому что в админке я создал страницу с этим урлом и привязал к ней этот шаблон, но как создать такую же страницу для элементов ? Ведь если /%category%/ всегда неизменен, то на месте /%postname%/ может все что угодно, например элемент_1, элемент_2,...,элемент_н.

Comment: Для вывода категорий используется шаблон `category.php`, не надо создавать отдельных страниц. Для обычных постов - шаблон `single-post.php`. То есть в папке вашей темы должен быть файл с таким именем. Если его нет, то Вордпресс ищет файл `single.php`. Наглядно показано на рисунке: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое). А что, если у меня таких категорий несколько. Например: `site/category_1/element`, `site/category_2/element`, то получается, для элементов из списка обеих категорий, будет одна страница - `single-post.php`, а надо, чтобы их было несколько.

И что, если у меня будет несколько категорий в одном урле, например: `site/category/local_category/element.`

Comment: 1) `single-post.php` это шаблон, он будет использоваться для отображения всех постов. Если какой-то один пост нужно вывести другим шаблоном, то используйте подключение шаблона по условию (см. http://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html#sposob-3-shablon-stranitsy-cherez-filtr-template_include-kodding и http://wp-kama.ru/id_89/uslovnyie-tegi-v-wordpress-i-vse-chto-s-nimi-svyazano.html). 2) Ничего страшного, в конечном итоге выводится пост, значит и будет использован шаблон поста.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас начну разбираться. А можете еще вот по какому вопросу подсказать. У меня есть посты, я их привязываю к рубрикам. Например, есть несколько постов о руководителях. Я создал рубрику "Руководство" и привязал к ней посты. А отображаю я эти посты так:
`<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
"numberposts" => "-1",
"category_name" => "Руководство",
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'ASC',
));

foreach ($posts as $post){
setup_postdata($post);
if(get_field("портрет_на_странице_руководства", get_the_ID(), false) != 1) {
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>`

Comment: Так вот суть в том, для фильтрации постов я использую `"category_name" => "Руководство"`, и тогда в `$posts` возвращаются лишь те посты, которые относятся к данной рубрике. Таких конструкций у меня штук 20 на весь сайт, и все работало. Но по непонятным причинам, теперь `get_posts()` ничего не возвращает, если в `$args` я передаю этот самый `"category_name"`. Вроде ничего не делал, а сайт можно сказать, работать практически перестал. Не знаете в чем может быть дело ? Всю голову сломал.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо русского названия указывать в том же названии slug категории.

Comment: Спасибо. Поменял на с русского на английский - все заработало. Но интересно, что когда я вернул обратно на русский, все все равно работает( Не понятно:)